# Logcat: make output using 'Log' class show full package name

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am using statements in my code in the same class that look like:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Writing command to initialize the FORA");
```

and

```
Log.i(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite signaled with status " + status);
```

yet the output from the first one is

`Writing command to initialize the FORA`

but the second one is

```
04-11 08:01:13.109 9030-9139/? I/com.lampreynetworks.ahd.transport.btle.b: onDescriptorWrite signaled with status 0
```

I would like to have the output with the package name in both cases. I thought that was determined by the TAG which in my case is

```
private static final String TAG = AndroidBtleHandler.class.getName();
```

I thought it might be because some of the statements were in a class within the class but that is not so. What do I need to do to get the full package name in the logcat output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not dependent on the message itself. If you have directly following info logs with Log.i() from the same class in your Logcat, only the first one shows the class name. (I don't know why that is.) It's the same with Log.w().

If you use Log.d(), the class name is shown every time.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the case. So its an easy solution if you want to know. On the plus side, if I do a filter with my package name, those lines that do NOT have a package attached for the reasons you stated are still displayed. This is really what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

public class App {

```
public static String getTag() {
    String tag = "";
    final StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 0; i < ste.length; i++) {
        if (ste[i].getMethodName().equals("getTag")) {
            tag = "("+ste[i + 1].getFileName() + ":" + ste[i + 1].getLineNumber()+")";
        }
    }
    return tag;
}
```

}

And instead of  Log.i(TAG, "Writing command to initialize the FORA"); use  Log.i(App.getTag(), "Writing command to initialize the FORA")

Comment: I will give it a try. But do you have any idea why the simple 'TAG' works most of the time but sometimes does not?